# What type of inter-rater reliability analysis should I do?

Tags: reliability

I have 16 pairs of raters. Each pair rated 5 items from one participant. There were a total of 16 participants. What type of inter-rater test should i do?

Comment: Why did you set it up this way? Are you trying to see if the two raters rated the participant the same way?

Also relevant: What was the nature of the ratings? Nominal? Ordinal? Interval?

Comment: I just want to know overall IRR for the measure not trying to see any differences between pairs.  Ratings are ordinal from 0 to 2.